# Share a Windows Printer over the Internet

Tags: networking, printing, share, firewall

I am trying to share a printer on a Domain connected Windows Server 2012 sever to be accessible over the internet by my domain users from non-domain workstations.

I have tried opening TCP 445 and TCP 139.

I can manage to get it working by adding a Local Port to the client, but not by a simple \server.com\sharename

If I do \server.com I can see the printer, but when trying to map it I get a error "Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000709). Double check the printer name and make sure that the printer is connected to the network."

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned our that TCP 445 and TCP 139 were all that was required.  THe issue was the the Print server needs to be setup to accept itself on a different DNS name.